# Кодировка русских символов POST HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, кодировка, post, httpurlconnection

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста. В сети информации много, но что-то у меня ничего не работает... Кусок кода приложения под андроид вынес в IntellJ IDEA :

```
try {
            final String text2 = "Привет";
            final String urls = "http://...";
            URL url = new URL(urls);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis());
            String charset = "UTF-8";
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";

            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data, charset=UTF-8; boundary=" + boundary);

            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"text2\"");
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(text2, "UTF-8"));
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
            String answer = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(answer);

            in.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            connection.disconnect();
        }catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Ошибка - " + e);
        }
```

на стороне сервера

```
$text = $_POST['text2'];
echo $text;
```

ответ в кракозябрах -
%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82

На английском все нормально

Где-то неправильно работаю с кодировкой... Как правильно применить кодировку?

Answer (score 3):

При формировании URL символы, не входящие в latin1 перекодируются алгоритмом [Percent-Encoding](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_URL). Содержимое POST-запроса кодируется точно так же. У вас в коде вижу такую строку:

```
outputStream.writeBytes(URLEncoder.encode(text2, "UTF-8"));
```

Подозреваю, что у вас ваш `HttpURLConnection` самостоятельно осуществяет кодирование параметров. А вы еще раз принудительно кодируете. Поэтому получаете такой результат.

**Дополнено:** Я ошибся насчет "самостоятельно кодирует". Никто ничего самостоятельно не кодирует. Вы когда отправляете без `URLEncoder.encode()` данные уходят в родной для Java кодировке UTF-16. Я нашел на английском SO [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759199/java-utf-8-encoding-not-working-httpurlconnection). На основе него рецепт для вашей проблемы такой:

```
// вместо строки DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
// пишем нижеприведенные две.
// OutputStreamWriter будет преобразовывать строку в UTF-8.

DataOutputStream tmpStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
BufferedWriter outputStream = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(tmpStream, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: если убрать URLEncoder.encode получаю - "@825B"

Comment: Ну как вариант можно потом полученный результат пропустить через `URLDecoder.decode(answer, "UTF-8")`

Comment: Но просто любопытно (лень самому написать), что получает php-скрипт. Пожалуйста выведите результат через `error_log(bin2hex($text))` и пришлите что там в логах будет. Или WireShark'ом запрос глянуть...

Comment: Обновил ответ. Должно заработать без "хака" с `URLDecoder`

Comment: Да, все работает, спасибо, помогло просто URLDecoder.decode ). спасибо.

Comment: попробовал error_log(bin2hex($text)) выводит "1"